# html file stored in apps use drawable stored in apps?

Tags: android, html, webview, drawable

I have an android apps with the webview. When i tried to set an image to be the background, i realized that **webview** will "overwrite" it, so **i cant use the direct background from xml**.

Now, i have an idea to insert the image in the html file instead of the xml. The image is stored at **res** folder, and its the same image that i used for the xml background.

I have tried something like this, but its not working :D

```
<article align="center" background:url('@drawable/background320x480')>
```

Is it possible to use the same image file for 2 backgrounds? (xml and webview) or is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

you should use `file:///android_res`:

```
<article align="center" background:url('file:///android_res/drawable/background320x480')>
```

Comment: if you try with th img tag, does it work? <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/background320x480" />

Comment: nope. The log cat says this : Incorrect res path: drawable/background320x480 :D

Comment: try putting the file extension (png or jpeg)

Comment: what getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.background320x480) returns?